# Is there an @angular/router equivalent to transition.from() in ui-router?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I am upgrading an Angular application from `ui-router` to `@angular/router` (v6).

---

There is a function which wants to find the previous route. Here is the implementation using `Transition` from `ui-router/core`

```js
    const newFromName = this.transition.from().name;
    this.transition.params('from')
```

I've removed most of the function as it shouldn't be relevant.

My question is:

> Is there an `@angular/router` equivalent to the above two lines?

We use 
`"@uirouter/angular-hybrid": "3.1.7"` 
`"@angular/router": "6.1.1",`

**Note: This is nothing to do with animations. I don't want to animate a transition, I just want to know what the previous route was.**

Added Clarification: An example would be if I was on a different route before navigating to this component e.g. `hello/world` and then navigated to the route with this code in `my/new/route`. I need to know the value `/hello/world`

Comment: There might be another solution, but I would create a service in which I subscribe to `router.events` and register the last route. In your component you inject the service and get the last route.

Comment: I've been browsing a bit for you, you can use the solution above or use [rxjs pairwise operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html) or use [ngrxstore](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store)

Comment: That doesn't help. I clarified the question a bit more. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, and in the `// Exit Code` you have access to the route you came from

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

...

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(e => {
    if(e instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // Init Code
    }

    if(e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // Exit Code
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This would be fine if the navigation occurred in this component. However, I am looking for the route previous to entering the component. Since this subscription is only active after the component has been initialised, I'm pretty sure it wouldn't pick it up.

Comment: @James If you need the route you come from, this works. Unless I didn't get your question

Comment: It doesn't appear to. If the navigation happened within this component and after the subscription was triggered. That would be fine, but I need to know the previous url regardless of where it came from. I have updated my question. Hope that helps. The `event` only tells me what the new route is when i subscribe to the router events

Answer (score 0):

## **Method 1 : Create a service**

```
@Injectable()   
export class RouterState {
  private routeHistory = [];

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // nothing to do
  }

  public startHistory() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(newUrl => this.routeHistory = [...this.routeHistory, newUrl]);
  }

  public getRouteHistory() {
    return this.routeHistory;
  }
}
```

In your app component :

```
constructor(private routerState: RouterState) {
  this.routerState.startHistory();
}
```

In your component where you need to get history :

```
constructor(private routerState: RouterState) {}

yourFunction() {
  const allRoutes = this.routerState.getRouteHistory();
  const lastUrl = !!allRoutes.length 
    ?  allRoutes.slice(-2)
    :  '';
}
```